# AWK search patter from to different row and make a sum

Tags: awk

I have this file:

```
100 230 a
104 310 b
```

I want to take second column of with the pattern `a` and add to the second column of the pattern `b`.

I tried something like this

```
awk '/a/ { var1=$2 } /b/ { var2=$2 } { print var1+var2}'
```

but don't work it shows me all the values of the colums. I don't seem to find the way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{print var1+var2}` is executed for each line of your file. If you want it to be executed at the very end after the last line, use `END{print var1+var2}`.